# Python pandas - ambiguous conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Why are these conditions ambiguous, please?

```
selected_F = selected.loc[ ((selected['L_ratio_5au'] > 0.1) & 
                  (selected['L_ratio_5au'] < 1)) or
                  ((selected['L_ratio'] > 0.1) & 
                  (selected['L_ratio'] < 1)) ]
```

I meant that at least one of the two columns 'L_ratio_5au' and 'L_ratio' has to be between the 0.1 and 1.0.

Thank you

Comment: Replace `or` by `|`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `|` (bitwise operator) instead of `or` (logical operator). You could also use `between` to simplify your expression:

```
selected_F = selected.loc[selected['L_ratio_5au'].between(0.1, 1, include='neither')
                          | selected['L_ratio'].between(0.1, 1, include='neither')]
```